# Build a Pandas DataFrame based on a combination of Series

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I need some advice on building DataFrames (Disclaimer: I'm trying to move away from Excel VBA and use Python and Pandas).

One particular task involves taking a list of string ids and replicating each line with additional info in some columns. Please see the tables below:

Step 1

```
    Cat_1    Cat_2    String-ID  
     null     null      apple        
     null     null      banana
```

Step 2 (Result)

```
Cat_1   Cat_2  String-ID  
A       AA     apple  
A       AB     apple  
A       AC     apple  
A       AD     apple  
A       AE     apple  
A       AA     banana  
A       AB     banana  
A       AC     banana  
A       AD     banana  
A       AE     banana
```

Logic:
For each string-ID, the string-id should be duplicated, so that in the category columns:

- Cat_1 - A is populated for every instance
- Cat_2 - AA, AB, AC, AD, AE are populated for each line

so, in total for one string-id (or one fruit), it should be duplicated 5 times so that the Category columns are populated (Step 2).

I have tried to import the source table into a dataframe and then tried to create a nested loop for step 2 but to no avail.

Columns Cat 1 and Cat 2 can be added via a list or Series as these will be limited and won't change.

Can anyone help on this please?

Comment: Hi there, please use cose blocks for your "steps", it is hard to read on a phone as is... also i don't understand the logic of your transformation, can you explain in detail?

Comment: @RichieV, apologies, I have reformatted the post and added the logic.

Answer (score 0):

You can populate the cat columns with lists of the values you want and then use `df.explode`

```
df['Cat_1'] = 'A'
df['Cat_2'] = ['AA', 'AB', 'AC', 'AD', 'AE']
df = df.explode('Cat_2', ignore_index=True)
```

You can only explode one column at a time, but say you needed Cat_1 to be `['A', 'B']`, then you could add a new explode line for `Cat_1`

Comment: Thanks @RichieV, I will give it a go and let you know.